# Facebook graph api. how to list all pages that my app is subscribed to?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So I am aware of how to check each page to get a list of all subscribed apps.

But I would like to get a list of all pages my app has real time update subscriptions for?

so i have tried this 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/$app_id/subscriptions?access_token=$app_token

but this just brings back basic info on the app.

I would like a list of pages that it has subscriptions to already?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look to be possible.

Endpoint you're using - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/app/subscriptions - is to get list of application webhooks (`callback_url` and type of changes), which are called subscriptions for some reason. It's not about pages that subscribed to this webhook (or this app in general).

Overall, even in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ for your app, under e.g. Messenger tab, you will only see *subset* of all pages that subscribed to this app. The visible subset is limited by your facebook user account permissions, presumably only show pages that you're either Admin or Editor.

Therefore, if such call would be possible, it would be somehow tied to User Access Token as well, not only app token.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Once logged, you can click on right button and select "Get User Access Token". You will need at least manage_pages or pages_show_list permission to accomplish this.

Now, all you have to do is call this endpoint: /me/accounts.

It should list all subscribed pages on your app.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

As per
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens
it is possible (graph api):

```
GET /oauth/access_token
?client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

And then `/<app_id>/subscriptions`

which returns something like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "application",
      "callback_url": "https:...",
      "active": true,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "ads_rules_engine",
          "version": "v2.9"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "object": "page",
      "callback_url": "https://...",
      "active": true,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "leadgen",
          "version": "v2.5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```